# Change View Controllers while maintaining users input data

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, segue

What is the best method to change between view controllers while keeping all text field data and segmented controller selections in the state the user chooses? Preferably in swift.

I have the need to change from 1 view controller to one of 3 others then always return to my main view controller before choosing the next controller to goto. I have found the using segues seems to reset my choices. Is there a way to navigate between controllers and leave the text fields populated? The actions that the user chooses impacts on some calculations on the main page. I want the user to be able to go back and forth adding and changing what they put in each page without re typing every box.

I would be grateful for any suggestions

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your data into `NSUserDefaults` and you can get that data anywhere, here is the simple example for you.

you can save data like this:

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject("your text from the text field", forKey: "YouKeyForThat")
```

after that you can get that data from any viewController like this way:

```
let loadedString = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("YouKeyForThat") ?? ""
```

In your case you can load it and populate the `textfield` in `viewDidLoad` method With the info from disk.

```
myTextField.text = loadedString
```

Comment: This Worked very well. I am now having issues where instead of each text field being repopulated with the string I saved, They are all comimg back as the One total I sent through to the main View controller. haha I will figure it out soon enough.
Thank You